# Flutter - How to sort retrieved lists using timestamp from Firebase Real-time database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to sort lists in a descending fashion from Firebase real-time database using timestamp, but I couldn't find a way to do that. I have tried a lot of things, but all of them are not working. Please help..

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("Products");

    productsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var KEYS = snap.value.keys;
      var DATA = snap.value;

      _bidBundlesList.clear();

      for (var individualKey in KEYS) {
        BidBundle bidBundle = new BidBundle(
            DATA[individualKey]['imageSrc'],
            DATA[individualKey]['productName'],
            DATA[individualKey]['productCat'],
            DATA[individualKey]['finalPrice'],
            DATA[individualKey]['startingPrice']);

        _bidBundlesList.add(bidBundle);
      }

      setState(() {
        this._bidBundlesList = _bidBundlesList;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('path')
        .orderByChild('timestamp')
        .onChildAdded
        .listen((Event event) {
      print(event.snapshot.value);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user3529601, but I guess that is for cloud firestore. What I want is for firebase realtime database.

Comment: its the same thing did you try this ?, i found that you can also use orderByChild() , 
orderByKey(),
orderByValue(), i edit my answer

Comment: yes, I have tried that, but it didn't work for me. I have added my code snippet now.